# Error when using a variable in recursion to iterate through a binary tree (Python)

Tags: python, recursion, tree

```
def berry_finder(t):
    """Returns True if t contains a node with the value 'berry' and 
    False otherwise.

    >>> scrat = tree('berry')
    >>> berry_finder(scrat)
    True
    >>> sproul = tree('roots', [tree('branch1', [tree('leaf'), tree('berry')]), tree('branch2')])
    >>> berry_finder(sproul)
    True
    """
    if is_leaf(t):
        if label(t)=='berry':
            return True
        else :
            return False    
    else:
        if label(t)=='berry':
            return True
        else:
            branch_list=[]
            for branch in branches(t)：   
                branch_list+=[berry_finder(branch)]                         
            if True in branch_list:
                return True
            else:
                return False
```

The code doesn't work.And the function's purpose is to find if any node's value is 'berry'.

The wrong part of the code is the recursion part(i.e. the code under the second `else`)

I wonder whethet it is the problem of the usage of `branch_list`,because the `branch_list` may change during the recursion?

Comment: can you give us all the code for the functions? It would be difficult for us to solve the issue when we don't know what the functions do

Comment: I have edited it ,sorry about that

Comment: I was talking about the `is_leaf`,`label` and `branches` functions

Comment: shorter: `for branch in branches(t): if berry_finder(branch): return True` and after `for`-loop `return False` - yo don't have to check all values but return `True` when you get first `True`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you reset `branch_list` in each iteration of the loop, so losing the previous boolean results, and ending up with only the last result.

You need to move that out of the loop, like so (but read on to reduce the code further -- step by step):

```
        branch_list=[]
        for branch in branches(t):
            branch_list+=[berry_finder(branch)]
```

Not a problem, but it is more natural to use `append` here:

```
        branch_list=[]
        for branch in branches(t):
            branch_list.append(berry_finder(branch))
```

And more pythonic is to build the list in one go through `map`:

```
        branch_list = list(map(berry_finder, branches(t)))
```

or comprehension:

```
        branch_list = [berry_finder(branch) for branch in branches(t)]
```

But you don't actually need to collect the booleans in a list at all. Just use `any`:

```
  return any(map(berry_finder, branches(t)))
```

The whole function can be reduced to just this:

```
def berry_finder(t):
    return label(t)=='berry' or any(map(berry_finder, branches(t)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You alread get answer how to use it with list

... but you don't need list for this because you can return `True` directly when `berry_finder(branch)` gives first `True`, and you can return `False` when you exit loop.

```
else:
    for branch in branches(t):
        if berry_finder(branch):  # 
            return True
    
    # --- after loop ---
    
    return False
```

---

**BTW:**

Instead of

```
    if True in branch_list:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

you can use shorter

```
    return (True in branch_list)   # you can even skip `()`
```

because `... in ...` gives `True` or `False`

Similar

```
    return (label(t) == 'berry')   # you can even skip `()`
```

And you would replace results

```
    if True in branch_list:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

you can use shorter

```
    return not (True in branch_list)
```

or

```
    return (True not in branch_list)
```

but it is not the same as `return (False in branch_list)`